# Sqoop export to Teradata is slow

Tags: export, teradata, cloudera, sqoop

I am trying to load ~700GB file to Teradata, using sqoop-connector-teradata-1.3c5.tar.gz[Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata]

the performance seems to be very slow.

I have included below parameters in sqoop command

```
sqoop export -D sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100 --connect jdbc:teradata://ip address/Database=dbname --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --username user --password pwd --table STG_TEST --export-dir /dirpath/ --input-fields-terminated-by "\t" --input-lines-terminated-by "\n" --connection-param-file /path/sqoop.properties --batch;
```

connection file includes

jdbc.transaction.isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED

Please suggest how to improve sqoop export performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered leveraging the 'internal.fastload' method for the Cloudier Connector to leverage Teradata's FastLoad utility mechanism? This would be faster than what may currently be running via 'INSERT...SELECT' statements. It will require that you load to an empty stage table then using a 'MERGE' or 'INSERT/UPDATE' statements to apply to the final target table.

Answer (score 0):

According to Clouderas documentation [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/connectors/latest/Teradata/Cloudera-Connector-for-Teradata/cctd_use_cctd.html), "the connector (1.3c5) automatically uses FastExport/FastLoad for better performance."

Looking at your command, you are not specifying any mappers.  Use more than one mapper to parallelize the job and improve performance.
From the Apache Sqoop Cookbook:

> The optimal number of mappers depends on many variables: you need to take into account your database type, the hardware that is used for your database server, and the impact to other requests that your database needs to serve. There is no optimal number of mappers that works for all scenarios. Instead, you’re encouraged to experiment to find the optimal degree of parallelism for your environment and use case. It’s a good idea to start with a small number of mappers, slowly ramping up, rather than to start with a large number of mappers, working your way down.